# Is there a way to essentially "override" a final variable?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I know you can't override variables, but is there a way to essentially "override" the final worker variable below?

```
public class ClassA {
   final protected CustomClass worker;

   public doComplicatedWork() {
        ....
        worker.doSomething();
        ....
   }
}
```

Essentially all I want to do is extend `CustomClass` and have `ClassA` do all the work as normal except `worker` would be my extended `CustomClass`.  Both `ClassA` and the original `CustomClass` are in a jar so I do not want to get involved with modifying them.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to bypass `final`:

```
  Field field = ClassA.getField("worker"));
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
  modifiers .setAccessible(true);
  modifiers .setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
  field.set(this, newWorker);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you need to do this. Presumably you pass `worker` as a  constructor argument to `ClassA`, so just construct your worker, and pass it to `ClassA`. Nothing in your question makes it sound like you need to weaken the `final` declaration.

Comment: `worker` is created using contructor arguments and is not passed as an argument unfortunately.

Comment: @SmittyWerbenjagermanjensen you'll have to modify the original source or use it differently, then. Probably just expose a constructor that takes CustomClass as a ctor argument. Sneaking around `final` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with using reflection if your constructor doesn't receive `CustomClass` worker as argument.

Code example:

```
class ClassA {
    final protected CustomClass worker = null;

    public void doComplicatedWork() {
    }

    public void printWorker(){
        System.out.println(worker); //testing method
    }
}

class CustomClass {
    ...
}

class NewCustomClass extends CustomClass{
    //Your new CustomClass
}
```

Using Reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    Field f = classA.getClass().getDeclaredField("worker");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(classA, new NewCustomClass());
    classA.printWorker();
}
```

It prints : `NewCustomClass@19d449fc` what means that we overrider it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Reflection, which should always be a last resort, you can simulate overriding that value by simply designing your accessors cleverly. ie:

```
public class SubClass extends ClassA
{
      final protected CustomClass subWorker;

      public CustomClass getWorker()
      {
          return this.subWorker;
      }
}
```

Provided the variable remains `protected`, you know the user can't get to it from outside of the class. Whenever they make a call to `getWorker` from `SubClass`, you've overridden it and it will retrieve the `subWorker` instead of the `worker`.

Comment: The problem with that is `ClassA` nevers call `getWorker()`.  It only uses it directly as `worker.___`

Comment: Okay.. I see your issue now. Again, it you replace references to `worker` with `getWorker()`, it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifying any of the classes in the jar which is one of the reasons my problem arose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not understanding it correctly, but.. couldn't you extend ClassA, and switch variable worker with your extended worker-class?

```
public class YourWorkerClass extends CustomClass 
{
     public DoSomething()
     { 
         //yourstuff
     }
}

public class YourClassA extends ClassA
{
    public YourClassA()
    {
        worker = new YourWorkerClass()
    }
}
```

Comment: it's 'final protected' in the base class, so you can't change it

Comment: It's final so that doesn't work.  That's what I originally intended to do though.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ClassA but essentially ignore the existing implementation and re-implement all the externals so that you use YOUR equivalent of "worker".